# How to process purchase for 2checkout with curl

Tags: php, curl, payment-gateway, 2checkout

I'm not sure if this was already asked in the forum but I was really having a hard time searching for answer. Is there an api way to submit a purchase on 2checkout using curl in php? cause currently what they are promoting is this sample:

```
<form action='https://www.2checkout.com/checkout/purchase' method='post'>
<input type='hidden' name='sid' value='1303908' />
<input type='hidden' name='mode' value='2CO' />
<input type='hidden' name='li_0_name' value='invoice123' />
<input type='hidden' name='li_0_price' value='25.99' />
<input type='hidden' name='card_holder_name' value='Checkout Shopper' />
<input type='hidden' name='street_address' value='123 Test Address' />
<input type='hidden' name='street_address2' value='Suite 200' />
<input type='hidden' name='city' value='Columbus' />
<input type='hidden' name='state' value='OH' />
<input type='hidden' name='zip' value='43228' />
<input type='hidden' name='country' value='USA' />
<input type='hidden' name='email' value='example@2co.com' />
<input type='hidden' name='phone' value='614-921-2450' />
<input name='submit' type='submit' value='Checkout' />
</form>
```

to which you'll use a javascript to submit or just simply click on the submit button to submit it but I don't want to use it cause this procedure might compromise the security of the site during the purchase or checkout process, I have already tried to create a curl code for this but it won't work

```
$curl = curl_init('https://www.2checkout.com/checkout/purchase');
        $data = array();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Accept: application/json"));
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "2Checkout PHP/0.1.0");
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
$data['sid']='1303908';...
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
```

This is how I did it but it won't add the purchase over on 2checkout, is there somebody who was able to do this already? If it's not possible with curl encryption of data maybe enough but I'm not sure how to do it which I can also use a secret word or something. Please I really need some enlightenment right now any answers are welcome here :(((

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did u find a solution for this? Im also facing the same issue

Comment: @AymanAbdel-Rahman No I haven't find any solution to this after I contact 2checkout about this issue they said they are still working on it so instead of using the 2checkout we just decided to switch into paypal and use their api for the transactions as we can't go on with the procedure they currently offer as it may compromise the security of our site, but try to contact them again and see if they have created an api for this, I last contacted them about this issue last year maybe somethings have changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I emailed 2checkout regarding this issue, and this was their response:

Unfortunately, due to the fact that the information is submitted through an HTML form, that does make it vulnerable to hackers. You could create the order from the Play Parameter set, where you would create the order in the 2Checkout vendor area, and just submit a product ID to us at the time of sale. that way, the hacker would not be able to alter the price.

Also, we do have some pre-built server side coding libraries that you can use to create an html form and automatically submit it to us with a call to the library. While it does still create an HTML form, there would be less chance for someone to alter it. The libraries are located here: https://www.2checkout.com/documentation/libraries if you want to take a look.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll check on this later. The thing why we didn't pursue on this api is because we need to set the products on their site directly which we don't want as it may add more cost on the clients side when customers buy for products, and we set our own ecommerce site where transactions are to be catered including payments. When you use their api its like you pay double you pay for the setup of your product on their site + there will be a charge for each transaction deducted against the customer payments that's normal but the client said it's like he won't get any return anymore.

Comment: Yeah, they do take a big margin for every transaction. Which payment gateway are you now using?

Comment: still paypal the good news is they accept credit cards the bad news is  it's only allowed in US not yet for other countries